# Symfony: Repository function does not fetch persisted state

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

After a form with Entity data is submitted, I want to check if certain properties have changed from their Database state. If so, I need to perform a different action than if it hasn't. I wrote the below code. It seems that the problem is that `getRepository()->findOneById()` does not get the value from the database but rather from some sort of cache. Maybe Symfony already considers `Dropoffpoint` changed at this juncture, and therefore the value of `Dropoffpoint->getCommission()` is always the same as the one retrieved from `getRepository->findOneById()->getCommission()`.

```
public function editDOPAction(Request $request, DOP $DOP) {
    $form = $this->createForm(DOPType::class, $DOP);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($DOP);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $existingDOP = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Dropoffpoint')->findOneById($DOP->getId()); # get DOP with same id
        if ($existingDOP) { # we found one
            if ($existingDOP->getCommission() != $DOP->getCommission()) {
                # commission changed (destructive!)
                $em->remove($existingDOP); #soft-delete the old DOP
                $em->persist($DOP); # persist a new DOP
            } else {
                $em->persist($DOP); # no destructive changes to DOP, just update as usual
            }
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep.  It is cached.  Clone the original $DOP and use it to compare against.

Comment: thanks, good advice!